# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when registering in pypitest

Tags: python, ssl, setup.py, pypi, software-packaging

I've followed Peter Down's instruction on pushing a package to PyPI on http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html

I have an account on PyPI Live and PyPI Test, I could log-in and the accounts were verified through the email.

But when I tried to run this within my repo:

```
python setup.py register -r pypitest
```

I get:

```
running register
running check
Registering [package_name] to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (500): <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Any idea what went wrong? I've my `~/.pypirc` file written accordingly to my username and passwords too.

How can this be resolved such that I can register the package on PyPI?

Comment: Found the solution, didn't like it. https://gist.github.com/alvations/14880b8b961d9c5c213cdfacb602ab34

Comment: Do you have your certificate trust store in order with the root and intermediate certificates?  I recently had this problem with a java web service client.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem with PyPI. And the PyPI servers are not maintained by me ;P

Comment: I was implying that perhaps the client does not have a complete SSL certificate chain in the trust store - this happened to me and it was very unexpected, yet true.  This tends to not be a problem on windows as it keeps its truststore updated, but with java and many other languages surprises do occur.  Can you turn on SSL tracing in your python interpreter?

Comment: I think it's too late. Now the error won't occur unless I am using a new account on PyPI. I will try to reproduce it tomorrow when it's the weekend with a new account =)

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: If you are using Python 3.6, you should have a look a this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify

Comment: In my case (using Conda and Python 3.5.1), the 500 response error disappeared after doing a `conda install ca-certificates`