# Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

Tags: python, macos, ssl

Many operations in Python require accessing things via https. This includes `pip install` command, or just using `http.client.HTTPSConnection`, or any modules or applications that use these things internally.

If python was installed from the official python pkg installer, downloaded from https://python.org, then it uses an internal version of openssl, and contains no root certificates. Anything that uses an SSL connection results in this error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

How can I install root certs to make the above error go away?

Comment: You should reinstall Xcode command line tools that contains Python.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68247505/4067700

Answer (score 249):

When you run the python installer, they display this information to you. It is also documented in `/Applications/Python 3.6/ReadMe.rtf`, but it's very easily overlooked.

Just browse to `Applications/Python 3.6` and double-click `Install Certificates.command`

There is an issue in the Python bug tracker about this.
http://bugs.python.org/issue29480

**Update:** This issue is marked as resolved in the bug tracker with this text being part of the latest comment:

> ... For 3.7.0b2, I have tried to make things more obvious in two ways.  One, the installer package will now attempt to open a Finder window for the /Application/Python 3.7 folder that contains the "Install Certificates.command".  Two, rather than just a generic "installation complete" message at the end of the install, there is now a tailored message that urges the user to click on the "Install Certificates.command" icon. ...

Comment: Is there a solution, if one doesn't have root access? Thanks.

Comment: I ran the Install Certificates.command file but the error persists (in Py36) if I use an https URL in my code (to read content). If I use the same URL string minus the "s" (e.g., http), my code works. Unfortunately, I need https for some URLs. Any suggestion for this? (I also ran "pip3 install --upgrade certifi" because I need both Py27 and Py36 running)

Comment: For those without root; check out this answer: https://bugs.python.org/issue29095

Comment: Thanks a lot, spend hours to find a solution till reach this answer. Awesome.

Comment: It's answers like these that spoil programmers ;)

Comment: This does not work; all errors persist, just as @ultrageek mentions. Also, please list the actual command instead of the alias that is bundled with a specific version of Python. -1.

Comment: @AaronCruz, The problem described here is a version-specific bundling bug, hence the link to version-specific script to fix it, and link to bug report that was closed in python 3.7. First try updating to latest python, or running the Install Certificates script. If that doesn't work, you're having a different problem, so next, ensure the server actually has the right certs - don't test cert validity with your browser, because browsers build caches of cert chains. Test with a tool like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or similar. If none of these help you, I don't know what you need.

Comment: Running `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command` in Terminal should work too.

Comment: Any idea what to do if I installed python using anaconda? I don't see Install Certificates.command anywhere

Comment: I don't have Python in my Applications folder

Comment: Could you mark this as the accepted answer? The problem is resolved in a way, at least closed in the python bug tracker.

Comment: @useranon did you ever figure it out? I also installed with Anaconda and can't seem to find the file everyone's talking about

Comment: @flppv you can run `which python3` to see where is this folder located. Then just `cd` in and use `open .` if you want to open the folder in your Finder.

Comment: @gma992 I installed python through homebrew and pyenv. I don't see an Install Certificaters command in the directory where my python version is stored.

Comment: Using venv with Python 3.9 and had to double-click on Install Certificates.command

Answer (score 61):

I solved this problem using this command:

```
open /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

I have Python 3.7 in my machine.

Comment: I have python3.9 and just changing the 7 for the 9 works, thank you!

Comment: thanks also works in python3.6, or just `python3.6 -m pip install -U certifi` works for me

Comment: This worked for me and solved my problem with lighstreamerClient

Answer (score 59):

Cool way to solve this issue for all your python version and without checking your version on macOS

```sh
bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command
```

This command is equivalent to:

```
...
bash /Applications/Python\ 2.7/Install\ Certificates.command
bash /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
bash /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
...
```

It helped me hope it will help you as well

Comment: % python3 get-pip.py --> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,

Comment: '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)

Comment: bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command

 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11: No module named pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 24, in main
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '

Comment: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11', '-E', '-s', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--upgrade', 'certifi']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Answer (score 44):

If pip does not fix the issue

```
pip3 install --upgrade certifi
```

Then try the following scripts if you can't find the "**Install Certificates.command**"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    # +++> if already done  <----
    #print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    #subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
    #    "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi
    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Probably the only solution that will work in many cases.

Comment: Works on ubuntu too! Thank god

Comment: Even though I found `Install Certificates.command`, I had to run this script to solve the problem. I had b0rked my environment pretty good with an overzealous `find ... -delete` which may have contributed.

Comment: I've had this problem intermittently for years, and this script solved it.  You are a hero amongst developers.

Comment: Spent a few hours on this and tried many other SO solutions... this is the only one that worked. I'm on Python 3.8 installed with Homebrew.

Comment: After many tries with different solutions, this finally fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Not all hereos wear capes and you just saved my life buddy ! Thanks (^_^)

Comment: I will be forever grateful to you.

Comment: Worked in Ubuntu! After so many tries, this is the only solution that worked for me! You're a God!

Comment: works in pyenv! thx

Comment: you're the man (y)
I have multiple python installations (from package and from homebrew) and i am totally lost. This script fixed the issue ! Run it with `python3 script_name.py` command

Comment: This was the only answer working for me on `MacOS M1 Sonoma`

Answer (score 11):

If you're using MacOS go to Applications >> python3.8 >> and double-click Install Certificates.command.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In my case none of the solutions worked with the system installed python3 in macOS Catalina, neither did it work with python3 installed via brew.

If someone has a situation like this and wants a quick solution, 
**Download and install python3 again, using https://www.python.org/downloads/**

**At the end of the installation, the installer would show you a note, asking to run the `Install Certificates.command` file.** 
(With the other installations, this file was not present, and neither was [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649450/2806163) with the file's source code working)

Restart the terminal, and you can type `where python3`, to see `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3`. Using this binary, the problem should not occur.

Note: It might be possible to make the system-installed python3 work, but in my case; it proved to be extremely hard, so I choose this way.

Comment: This led me to the correct solution on Catalina when trying to get my bitbar python3 plugins working. I saw I had a couple python3 installations with `which python3` and changing the script shebang to `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` fixed the SSL errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem, when I tried to run Python with Keras data loading. The error for me was:

```
Exception: URL fetch failure on AWS_URL: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)
```

I fixed my problem by upgrading the certificate as:

```
pip install --upgrade certifi
```

Comment: Hi! It is `pip install --upgrade certificate` isn't it? I made an edit to your post, but wasn't sure if this is a spelling mistake or a module I don't know.

Comment: Or is it this [module](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/)? Then please feel free to correct it!

Comment: It’s not a spelling mistake, but just a module name.

Answer (score 3):

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=$(python -m certifi)
```

worked like a charm. Make sure you have installed certifi beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

Confirm you are not in a virtualenv.
I tried the above without success, only to realise my installations were failing because I was on a virtualenv

Comment: How to make it work in virtual environments?

Comment: @ValentinoPereira check the python version  in the virtual env, and try update it using  "/Applications/Python {version}/Install Certificates.command"

Answer (score 2):

I did this and it worked on my Mac:
Macintoch HD>Applications>Python file>Install Certificates.command (double click on it)

Answer (score 1):

A cheap way around this is just using python3.5 if you still have it installed.

Pushing to PyPI:

`python3.5 setup.py register -r pypitest`

`python3.5 setup.py sdist upload -r pypitest`

pipping seems to work fine with 3.6 out of the box..

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with macOS Big Sur. Here is what I did to solve the issue.

IDE - Pycharm

Python Version Downloaded - 3.9.6

- Download the latest python version and remove the earlier version
- While installation, at the end (Summary Section), there is a small note to install an SSL Certificate. Read that Summary section carefully.
- Double click the SSL Certificate path provided in the summary
- It will take you to the respective folder where there should be one file named - "Install Certificate Command"
- Double click on that file, it should open the terminal and will run the code automatically. Wait till you receive the message as "[Completed Successfully]".
- Once done close and restart terminal/IDE and this should resolve your issue.

Note: if you have anaconda and python both installed on your system then check whether you are using the correct python version in the IDE which the latest version downloaded and not from Anaconda.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add my corporate CA certs into the python CA cert file due to corporate SSL gateways.

The location of the CA cert file is found by

```
import ssl
print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)
```

The cert to be added was in keychain. After exporting it, it needed converting into PEM format so it could be cut & pasted into the cacert file -

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in cert.cer -out cert.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you do not have `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable set. I had the same problem, it took a while before I figured out some application was setting this variable as an empty string inside my bash profile.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was a misspecification of the request. I'd made a `https` call instead of a `http` call. Changing to http solved it.

Answer (score -1):

sometimes if you're using conda or poetry you may be in a virtual environment shell. you can check with:

`which python`

for me the solution was as simple as `cmd+t` to open a new shell.

Answer (score -2):

Just REINSTALL your Python on your Mac

Answer (score -3):

If you're using macOS open finder and go to Applications > Python3.7 folder (or whatever version of python you're using)  > double click on "Install Certificates.command" file.