# extracting Yahoo Historic data with fix_yahoo_data

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, yahoo-finance, pandas-datareader

I am trying to extract historic yahoo finance data on Anaconda using Python 3.5 using the code below:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance 

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("SPY", start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(["SPY", "IWM"], start="2017-01-01", end="2017-04-30")
```

It was working up until a few days ago when it started giving me the below message:

```
 File "C:\Users\tedy\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
```

Does anyone know what I can do to get it working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334357

and

[Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

Make sure you have everything installed correctly do use SSL on python 3.5.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thomas it seems to be working. Following the links you gave: I made sure the Python Module certifi was installed and then imported it before running the get_data_yahoo function