# brew installation of Python 3.6.1: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl

I installed python 3.6 using

`brew install python3`

and tried to download a file with `six.moves.urllib.request.urlretrieve` from an https, but it throws the error

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)

In the Python installation (from .pkg), the README indicates that one needs to run the `Install Certificates.command` after the installation [to](https://bugs.python.org/msg276516)

1. install `certifi`
2. symlink the certification path to `certify` path

to be able to use certificates.

However, in brew install, this file does not exist and it does not seem to be run.

Comment: Executing `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command` in Terminal fixed this problem with my homebrew python3 installation.

Comment: Given the popularity of this question, I fielded [a issue to brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/42198#issue-470594759).

Comment: `export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs` worked for me in Mac OS Big Sur.

Comment: This [comment by robo-corg](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/42198#issuecomment-564181886) points out the root of the cause. I. e., it is the missing `/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem`. Now on a mac, you have that file in `/private/etc/ssl/`. So running, `ln -s /private/etc/ssl/cert.pem /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem` sym links the certificate. And, that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It seems that, for some reason, Brew has not run the `Install Certificates.command` that comes in the Python3 bundle for Mac. The solution to this issue is to run the following script (copied from `Install Certificates.command`) after `brew install python3`:

```
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What does one do, if one does not have root access / sudo rights? Thanks.

Comment: I ran the above command and it seemed to work successfully, but I am still getting the error.  Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: For reference, the source of this script is here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Mac/BuildScript/resources/install_certificates.command

Comment: @tommy.carstensen you will have to just run this for your own virtual environments

Comment: I had to add `import ssl; ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_stdlib_context` to my code for it to work.

Comment: This post also helped with ssl errors on mac. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630381/3380256

Comment: This was required for me to start development of my Slack App. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked after many days of trying different solutions <3

Comment: Had this issue on macOS Ventura 13.4. I updated `certifi`, copied the `Install Certificates.command` source and ran it, but unfortunately no dice. Rafael's suggestion was the last thing I needed.

Answer (score 35):

My solution for Mac OS X:

1) Upgrade to Python 3.6.5 using the native app Python installer downloaded from the official Python language website https://www.python.org/downloads/

I've found that this installer is taking care of updating the links and symlinks for the new Python a lot better than homebrew.

2) Install a new certificate using "./Install Certificates.command" which is in the refreshed Python 3.6 directory

> cd "/Applications/Python 3.6/"
>   sudo "./Install Certificates.command"

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me, and I'm on 3.8 (changed the command appropriately to the Python 3.8 directory).

Comment: There is no Python folder in my Applications, and I could not locate it on my machine. Any ideas how can I fix the issue for my case?

Comment: @talha06 - In order to know where Python is located on your computer, open the python shell typing `python` or `python3` then `import sys` and `print('\n'.join(sys.path))`  

Or you can type this command in the terminal `python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"`

Comment: Thanks worked for me with tiny change:
`$ cd /Applications/Python 3.8/`
`$ sudo ./Install\ Certificates.command`

Happy Coding :)

Comment: After 2 dys of searching. this is what worked for me. Didn't even make it to the approved solution.

Answer (score 26):

- find out default cafile:

```sh
python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)'
```

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/cert.pem

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/certs
```

- find out ca file of `certifi`

```sh
python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())'
```

> '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'

- copy to

```sh
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem
```

Comment: This did not work for me on a conda python environment, using conda python. I tried copying the certs in three different directories: ssl, ssl/crt, etc/ssl/certs . I have found no solution so far.

Comment: @user1255933 how did you solve this?

Comment: This is the correct answer to this question, awesome way to find the default `cert.pem`!

Comment: Thank you.  My work uses Zscaler and I was using a miniconda python install.  This gave me the clue I needed to find the offending openssl_cafile.  I copied the Zscaler root CA over /Users/xxx/miniconda3/ssl/cert.pem and my problem was solved.

Comment: The output from `python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)'` was a non-existing file for me. I simply copied the file at the path from `python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())'` to the path of the former command. The exact steps in this answer did not work for me. Using RHEL7

Answer (score 11):

For temporary, following will disable the ssl checking,

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: This solves the immediate problem, but is *NOT RECOMMENDED*: you run the risk of putting a vulnerable service into production this way.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It makes using TLS pointless.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to make your local root certificate (e.g. `local_RootCA.crt`) become trusted by python, you can add it into the end of `certifi/cacert.pem` file:

```
cat local_RootCA.crt >> `python -c 'import certifi; print(certifi.where())'`
```

That solution works good for macos brew python 3 installation as well.

Comment: After a day of trying different things in this and other SOF conversations, this is what worked for us. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to find this file in Application -> Python folder.

On MAC Press Command + Space to open Spotlight Search and type 'Install Certificates.command', then execute it. This solution resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

positionning SSL_CERT_FILE env var to your ca file also works and it is not invasive.