# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with urllib

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I'm running into trouble with the module urllib (Python 3.6). Every time I use the module, I get a page's worth of errors.

what's wrong with urllib and how to fix it?

```
import urllib.request
url='https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/artificial-intelligence'
u1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(u1)
```

That block of code likes to spit out this mouthful of stuff:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a-nguyen/Downloads/EzSorses/APAsauce.py", line 3, in <module>
    u1 = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)>
```

Seems like something's off with the module itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)

Comment: How much do you want to bet someone will suggest disabling the cert checking? Well, if someone does, don't do that ;)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is command line program that you can run on MacOsX that will install the certificates:

```
sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

The `sudo` command will prompt for you password to elevate your privileges.

Answer (score 26):

a dirty (not safe in terms of security) but fast hack like this do the job for me:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: This is extremely dangerous as it can unknowingly impact all downstream users. It should never ever be done. At least create and use an unverified context instead as `urlopen(url, context=ssl.SSLContext()` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. My python version is 3.6.5 and I'm on Mac OSX. When I tried to connect to the `HTTPS` sites I started getting the

`<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>`

exception. So, it was so obvious to me that the python on my machine has no certificates. I just ran the file from the path `/Applications/Python 3.6` with a file name Install `Certificates.command`. This solved my issue.
I reffered to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error).

Comment: This resolves the problem on Python 3.6. See the associated issue here: https://bugs.python.org/issue28150

Comment: where is this on linux rhel?

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem, open your **bash** and write:

```
cd /Applications/Python 3.6
```

then:

```
sudo Certificates.command
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, but this answer did https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953648/1274947

Comment: And for me that answer did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649450/1338797 - and not because I ran the code, but because I found out about the `SSL_CERT_FILE` variable, by running `import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())`