# While running my python code it is giving me error "ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, openssl, boto3

I am currently new with the boto and SSL. I am running a code which creates instances in AWS. When I run the code (tried on global and virtual env both) I get the error:

> self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:726)

I checked various posts but none of them work. Cross checked my .aws, installed certifi. Checked openssl:

```
$ python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"      
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018.
```

Do I need to some how insert openssl in my virtual environment?

Edit 1- For the temporary fix

```
$  export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
```

Comment: Your Certificate Verification is failing which could be due to reasons like the CA certificate not being present on the Client to verify the server's certificate.

Comment: @Jay I don't think failing certification is the reason because for other people in my organisation it is working fine

Comment: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED - This error is thrown only when there is a certificate verification failure.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late here. But for me this helped.

> This is an answer to a similar problem by user andilabs!

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Find out more here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172355/3548966