# MNIST dataset loadin:ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python

I am trying to load data from `MNIST` data set. I am using python 3.6 with jupyter notebook on my machine.

I am using the below code but it is giving me error every time. Please help to understand what is the meaning of this error in simple language and how can I resolve this issue.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

> c:\users\gaurav_pendhari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function fetch_mldata is deprecated; fetch_mldata was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22`enter code here`
>     warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
>   c:\users\gaurav_pendhari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\deprecation.py:77: DeprecationWarning: Function mldata_filename is deprecated; mldata_filename was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in version 0.22
>     warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
>
> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: This looks relevant, especially the information at the bottom: https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

The '`fetch_mldata()`' is gone for good/deprecated[[1]](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10779) and is replaced by '`fetch_openml()`' [[2]](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_openml). The following worked on macOS Mojave with `Python 3.7.3`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
X, y = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1, return_X_y=True)
# or #
mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
```

If this gives an error on SSL certificate  [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183801/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-urllib), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error), [5]](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10779), then (on mac) type in terminal:

```
$sudo /Applications/Python\ 3.7/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Note: "3.7" because that was the version installed in Jupyter Notebook. To check version of Python run this in a cell [[6]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694528/how-to-know-which-is-running-in-jupyter-notebook):

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```