# How to get rid of SSL Error in Python for safe websites?

Tags: python, macos, ssl-certificate

I am new to Python and coding and was trying to learn web scraping. I am getting the **certificate verification error**. I have read other posts suggesting setting `(verify = False)` but others discouraged this for safety reasons.

I tried to install `pip3 install certifi` and I get (Requirement already satisfied:)

Code line:

```py
urllib.request.urlopen("https://automatetheboringstuff.com").read()
```

Error:
`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>`

I tried other websites, like google and yahoo which appear safe and Safari is accepting its certificate, but when I try with Python I get the same error.

Is there a safe solution to this?

Comment: On which OS are you ? Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183801/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-urllib)?

Comment: I have Catalina. I look at both posts. The first one discouraged setting the ssl to unverified
context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

Someone else suggested adding/updating certificates.

> pip install certifi

> Requirement already satisfied: certifi in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2020.12.5)

Comment: Also tried:

> /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi'
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: It finally worked. There is a file named (install certificate.command) within Python folder in applications. I had to run that file.

Comment: I'm happy for you, it was one of the most upvoted answer in the (first) so question I linked. As a suggestion for the next time, try to search about your problem as first!