# Getting data (room temperature) from an auth website to visualize it

Tags: php, json, python-3.x, python-requests, data-visualization

I'm wondering how to get data (room temperature) from a specific website that links to a temperature monitor and then visualize this data....
I tried to use (requests) in python but it didn't work or there is something missing.. So anyone knows what is the best way or which programming languages are the best (python, PHP or other) and how we can get this data by using the API.

Comment: do you want to get your room temperature from API??????

Comment: I'm quite sure that I need to use API to access the website and get the data from the website, but not sure how to use this stuff!?

Comment: can you explain what exactly want to do?

Comment: I need to get live data (room temperature) from a website and visualize it in a graph and then showing a brief history of data points over time

Comment: there is no way easier than python requests package. its usage is very simple.

Comment: When I use requests to get the data, I have received an error:
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xx.xxx.xx.xx', port=xxx): Max retries exceeded with url: /smartweb/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Comment: I don't know python but if you ask your error in other question maybe find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I dont how do you mesure the temperature but it should be possible if the thermometer has an api. So we could interact with it.
Concerning your error '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]'
i recommend you to visit [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED with urllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183801/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-with-urllib)
hope this helped you :)