# urllib.request.urlopen(URL) not working in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urllib2, urlopen

I am trying to access JSON using urllib.request.urlopen. It works fine when I use urllib2 in python2, but not urllib.request.urlopen.

```
URL = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest'

f = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1316, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1391, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 415, in wrap_socket
    _session=session
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 826, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1080, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 701, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:864)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a1.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(getLatestRates())
  File "a1.py", line 15, in getLatestRates
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1359, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:864)>
```

Comment: Are you behind some firewall or using a public wifi with "captive" screen?

Comment: Are you on windows or mac? Do you have the root certificates installed with Python3.7?

maybe you should read this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) is likely the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used and it worked:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

URL = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest'
f = urlopen(URL)
```

I hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to disable the ssl verification

```
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an issue with error in *request.py*:

**_load_windows_store_certs** caused *MemoryError*

Fixed by updating python from version **3.7.4** to **3.8.1**

Hope this help