# SSLCertVerificationError - Geopy - unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

Tags: python, ssl, geopy

Im trying simple queries like this (which come in geopy [documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='testing')
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC")
print(location.raw)
```

but I get this error:

```
    GeocoderServiceError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
    certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Does anybody knows how to fix it and make it run?

I have python 3.8 on Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Fix your python system setup, maybe install https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

Comment: already install certifi but its still not working ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue in this:

[brew installation of Python 3.6.1: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate/44649450#44649450)

Basically, for some reason, Brew did not run the Install Certificates.command that comes in the Python3 bundle for Mac.