# I cannot open a python programme file because it keeps closing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to this, so keep that in mind.

Every time i try to run/execute the file it just closes straight away.

This is what it says before it closes
[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67rnJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click your python file and Click Edit -> Edit with IDLE

```
F5 to run the code in IDLE
```

Then you can see the error and try to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an SSL Error. So I guess you try to connect to a server. YOu might try to connexct to taht se cer manually (perhaps with a browser) to see wheter the certificate is correct.

Do you have more information about your program? Is it online avaible?

If you dont want to have the Pyhtonshell avaible after the crash, you can run `python3 -i yourprogram.py`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SSL certificates have not been installed on your system. You can try execute `Install Certificates.command`, located at /Applications/Python\ 3.x/ (or OS-specific location)

If that fails, you may manually copy certificates to the required location. This may be possible by following steps enumerated by Ken in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61294657)

Hope it solves your problem