# How to setup ssl connection in Azure redis cache with python?

Tags: python, azure, redis, azureportal, azure-redis-cache

We have a premium subscription in azure portal.

i just want to know what is the difference between ssl_cert_reqs or ssl=True

if i am making connection with below will this is secured?

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host=myHostname, port=6380,
                      password=myPassword, ssl_cert_reqs='none', ssl=True)
```

if it's not secured how i can create a certificate file for that?
looks like if SSL is enabled we need to specify **ssl_ca_certs**, where to get this file? or do we need to generate it with some azure service?.

```
For Azure Cache for Redis version 3.0 or higher, TLS/SSL certificate check is enforced. ssl_ca_certs must be explicitly set when connecting to Azure Cache for Redis
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-python-get-started

Comment: You can follow up with this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate/44649450#44649450

Comment: Through that article, has your problem been solved?

Comment: yes.. it worked for me

Comment: You can post your answer to help more people . ^-^