# Flask + sqlalchemy certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, sqlalchemy

I am connecting to a remote mysql database (on my local network) from a flask app using ssl connection.

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://user:password@192.168.1.24/AwesomeDB?ssl_ca=client-ssl/ca.pem&ssl_cert=client-ssl/client-cert.pem&ssl_key=client-ssl/client-key.pem"
```

Any call to the database throws this mysterious error.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.24' ([SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: IP address mismatch, certificate is not valid for '192.168.1.24'. (_ssl.c:1122))")
```

I can log into the mysql monitor from terminal just fine.

```sh
mysql -u user -p -h 192.168.1.24 --ssl-ca=client-ssl/ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-ssl/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-ssl/client-key.pem
```

I am on macos 11.0.1 and python 3.9.0.
I have tried installing and linking `certifi` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649450/11357889). Everything works fine without ssl. Please help.

Edit: the problem is not specific to macos, I tried connecting from ubuntu with the same result.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#pymysql-ssl

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue when trying to connect to CLoudSQL(GCP)using Flask SQL alchemy over SSL. Looks like CLoudSQL somehow prefers *mysqlconnector* over *pymysql* driver when used with Flask SQL alchemy. So replacing the *pymysql* driver with *mysqlconnector* in SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI did the trick.

Make sure you have mysqlconnector package installed

```
pip install mysql-connector-python via pip
```

Here's a small snippet of the working code

```
>>> from flask import Flask
>>> from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
>>>
>>> app = Flask(__name__)
>>>
>>> app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"]=False 
>>>
>>> app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://{username}:{password}@{db_hostname}/{database}?ssl_ca=server-ca.pem'
>>>
>>> db = SQLAlchemy(app)
>>>
>>> class User(db.Model):
...   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...   username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
...   email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return '<User %r>' % self.username
...
>>> db.create_all()
>>>
>>> admin = User(username='admin', email='admin@example.com')
>>> guest = User(username='guest', email='guest@example.com')
>>>
>>> db.session.add(admin)
>>> db.session.add(guest)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>>
>>> User.query.all()
[<User 'Flask'>, <User 'admin'>, <User 'guest'>]
```

Note: In cases wherever possible, it is preferred to use pymysql adapter as it's [more performant](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/PyMySQL_evaluation#MySQL_DB_Drivers_Comparison) even though mysqlconnector is officially supported by Oracle. Both are implemented in pure python though.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66403127/2144390

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Thanks for pointing it out. updated the link: here's a nice document that compares different MySQL DB drivers: https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/PyMySQL_evaluation#MySQL_DB_Drivers_Comparison

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs, "If the server uses an automatically-generated certificate that is self-signed or does not match the host name (as seen from the client), it may also be necessary to indicate ssl_check_hostname=false"

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#ssl-connections

So you could try :

`app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+pymysql://user:password@192.168.1.24/AwesomeDB?ssl_ca=client-ssl/ca.pem&ssl_cert=client-ssl/client-cert.pem&ssl_key=client-ssl/client-key.pem&ssl_check_hostname=false"`

and see how it goes. This did the trick for me.

Comment: I get an error with the above config
```__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_check_hostname'```

Am using the same mysql+pymysql. How did you fix this?