# read_sql() from MySQL is extremely slow

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using MySQL with pandas and sqlalchemy. However, it is extremely slow. A simple query as this one takes more than 11 minutes to complete on a table with 11 milion rows. What actions could improve this performance? The table mentioned does not have a primary key and was indexed only by one column.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
sql_engine_access = 'mysql+pymysql://root:[password]@localhost')
sql_engine = create_engine(sql_engine_access, echo=False)
script = 'select * from my_database.my_table'
df = pd.read_sql(script, con=self.sql_engine)
```

Comment: Are you pulling those rows down from a cloud instance or a relatively slow network connection? One million rows per minute is 16.7 thousand rows per second which is not abysmally slow (about half the speed of my local LAN connection).

Comment: all the records were fetched using sqlachemy execute command from python. To do that, it took more than 12 hours (to fetch about 11 million rows and 58 columns). The server is installed at the same computer as the python code was run. No LAN or cloud access. This computer has 32 gb of memmory and an AMD processor with 12 cores, using MS Windows 10 pro.

Comment: I did also observe that the disk is being used heavily during these processes

Answer (score 4):

You can try out our tool [connectorx](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) (`pip install -U connectorx`). It is implemented in Rust and targeting on improving the performance of `pandas.read_sql`. The API is basically the same with `pandas`. For example in your case the code would look like:

```
import connectorx as cx
conn_url = "mysql://root:[password]@localhost:port/my_database"
query = "select * from my_table"
df = cx.read_sql(conn_url, query)
```

If there is a numerical column that is evenly distributed like ID in your query result, you can also further speed up the process by leveraging multiple cores like this:

```
df = cx.read_sql(conn_url, query, partition_on="ID", partition_num=4)
```

This would split the entire query to four small ones by filtering on the `ID` column and `connectorx` will run them in parallel. You can check out [here](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x#examples) for more usage and examples.

Here is the benchmark result loading 60M rows x 16 columns from MySQL to pandas DataFrame using 4 cores:
[image: mysql time]
[image: mysql memory]

Answer (score 2):

While perhaps not the entire cause of the slow performance, one contributing factor would be that PyMySQL (`mysql+pymysql://`) can be significantly slower than mysqlclient (`mysql+mysqldb://`) under heavy loads. In a very informal test (no multiple runs, no averaging, no server restarts) I saw the following results using `df.read_sql_query()` against a local MySQL database:

| rows retrieved | mysql+mysqldb (seconds) | mysql+pymysql (seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_000_000 | 13.6 | 54.0 |
| 2_000_000 | 25.9 | 114.1 |
| 3_000_000 | 38.9 | 171.5 |
| 4_000_000 | 62.8 | 217.0 |
| 5_000_000 | 78.3 | 277.4 |

[image: chart.png]

Comment: Thank you Thompson, for your answer and for improving my question. In fact, I changed to "mysql+mysqldb//" and my query went to 4 mind instead of 11. It is much better, though I believe there is still room to improve the performance with other actions.