# Trouble for downloading mp3 file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recaptcha, urllib

I'm new to coding and have been stuck at one point trying to download an mp3 file.
I can access the file but not download it; it produces a variety of problems while executing this code's downloading mp3 file portion. Please, could you assist me?
I'm using the MAC platform with PyCharm.

## CODE STARTS FROM HERE

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
import urllib.request
```

## Sample Audio URL

```
url = 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3'
path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
```

## creating a webdriver

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver: WebDriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/Users/sam/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
```

## get the mp3 audio file

```
src = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/video/source").get_attribute("src")
print("[Audio File Path:] ",src)
```

## downloading mp3 file

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, path+"//sample.mp3")
```

#---------- END OF CODE --------------

## ERRORS

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1253, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1299, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1248, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1008, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 948, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1422, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sam/PycharmProjects/BB/practice.py", line 35, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, path+"//sample.mp3")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 239, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)>

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the missing certificates of the python library causing issues with the urllib. Please refer to the below url in  order to resolve the certificate issue :

[brew installation of Python 3.6.1: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate/44649450#44649450)

Comment: That's awesome bro! It fixed the script :)
Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.