# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when trying to load tfhub universal-sentence-encoder

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate

im getting a "URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1125)>" when trying to load the universal-sentence-encoder as such:

```python
import tensorflow_hub as hub
hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4')
```

i tried to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44649449/brew-installation-of-python-3-6-1-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate/44649450#44649450) and it worked the first couple of times, but now it isn't working. however, i get a 200 status code if i try something like this:

```python
import requests

x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')

print(x.status_code)
200
```

how i can fix this error? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MacOS try running this

```
/Applications/Python\ YOUR_PYTHON_VERSION_HERE/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Comment: i am on macos monterey, but that didn't work for me