# downloading ResNet50 in Keras generates "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using python 3.6 and Keras (2.0.9) over Tensorflow

trying to download trained models of resnet50 but encounter the following error:
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)

the following is the code used:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

img_path = 'elephant.jpg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
model.summary()
preds = model.predict(x)

print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=3)[0])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

Answer (score 35):

You can consider [this](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/issues/33#issuecomment-397257502).

I also use the SSL module before downloading the data set. It solved this problem!

Like this:

```
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

Comment: Works, but what exactly is this doing?

Comment: Does not work, getting a 403 foridden error for github: Exception: URL fetch failure on https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/releases/download/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5: 403 -- Forbidden

Comment: I had the same problem for "InceptionV3" -- the solution helped in my case.

To answer @wordsforthewise 's question: I guess that this way you "allow" downloading from "unverified" domains. Maybe SSL certificate expired for the domain or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

Just ran into the same issue. I found the answer here:
[Mac OSX python ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

Browse to Applications/Python 3.6 folder and double-click Install Certificates.command

I tested it on Mac and it worked.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Combining either or both the @[Roman Mirochnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5714661/roman-mirochnik) and @[sos418](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5453953/sos418) method should work i.e.

1. Browse to `Applications/Python 3.x` folder and double-click Install `Certificates.command`
2. Add to code:

   ```
   import ssl
   ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
   ```