# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Python 3.6 mac osx can't fix with 'Install Certificates.command'

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, suds, macos-high-sierra

I am [aware of the update in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify) where you need to run the 'Install Certificates.command' in order to get SSL working again, however it doesn't seem to work for me.

Running the file results in:

```
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
 Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2018.4.16)
  -- removing any existing file or link
  -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
  -- setting permissions
  -- update complete
```

And I've also explicitly run

```
pip3 install certifi
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2018.4.16)
```

Yet when I try to run my application ([using suds-py3](https://pypi.org/project/suds-py3/)) I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_docs.py", line 38, in <module>
    session = Client(url_SessionWebService)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 111, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 151, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/wsdl.py", line 135, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 78, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/reader.py", line 94, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 174, in open
    return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 63, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/suds/transport/http.py", line 119, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 564, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 756, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)>
```

I've also tried adding the following to bypass:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

But the resulting call seems to indicate that the request was not authenticated

Any suggestions on how to further debug this?

Comment: [try](https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3)

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved the problem in my side:
**to install certifi do this:**

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade certifi --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

You just copy and paste that command in your Mac terminal or any IDE terminal such as Visual Studio code.