# WAS Slackbot Integration from WAS Landing Page errors when following the instructions

Tags: bots, ibm-watson, slack, watson-assistant-solutions

"https://watson-personal-assistant.github.io/developer/further-topics/slackbot-integration/"

I am not able to make it work by following the steps on WAS Slack Bot Integration (above link).

1. My slack setting should be ok as I tried use the same ID and API token to connect to another program successfully.
2. I installed Python 3.7 initially, but downgrading to 3.6.2 as document suggested
3. "python3 bot.py" results as following - with exception stack

   ```
   Forests-MacBook-Pro:simple_WA_slackbot fmlin$ python3 bot.py
   Not On Bluemix...
   Environment Variables Loaded Successfully
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 179, in connect_slack_websocket
       http_proxy_auth=proxy_auth)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 494, in create_connection
       websock.connect(url, **options)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 217, in connect
       options.pop('socket', None))
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 126, in connect
       sock = _ssl_socket(sock, options.sslopt, hostname)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 253, in _ssl_socket
       sock = _wrap_sni_socket(sock, sslopt, hostname, check_hostname)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_http.py", line 232, in _wrap_sni_socket
       server_hostname=hostname,
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
       _context=self, _session=session)
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
       self.do_handshake()
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
   ```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/client.py", line 52, in rtm_connect
    self.server.rtm_connect(use_rtm_start=with_team_state, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 147, in rtm_connect
    self.connect_slack_websocket(self.ws_url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 186, in connect_slack_websocket
    raise SlackConnectionError(message=str(e))
slackclient.server.SlackConnectionError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
Connection failed. Invalid Slack token or bot ID?
Forests-MacBook-Pro:simple_WA_slackbot fmlin$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `/Applications/Python 3.6.2/Install Certificates.command` program to install the root certificates needed to validate SSL connections, as it looks like your Python installation's SSL certificate verification is failing.

[See more information about this program here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098127/866021)

Comment: Thanks so much Adil. It really helped! Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you used the right Bot ID?

Did you set the user environment variable BOT_ID in the .env file?

Did you properly create the bot in slack using the instructions in the instructions
https://github.com/Watson-Personal-Assistant/simple_WA_slackbot

Getting Your Slack Key

```
Go to https://YOUR_SLACK.slack.com/apps/manage
In the Search App Directory field at the top, type Bots
Click on Bots
Click on the Add Configuration button
Give your bot a unique username (Save this info)
Save the API Token
You will use these variables when creating your .env file as instructed in the below steps
```