# How to update SSL certificates on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ssl, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm having a problem with python package `requests-html`. When the package is trying to download chromium, I'm getting an error:

> ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   (_ssl.c:1056)

It's the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify/42098127#42098127) and it has been resolved for Mac. Any idea how can I fix this on Windows? In case it matters, installing packages with PIP works fine. Windows 8, Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `verify=False` in your request args?

This should make the request ignore SSL Cerificate requirements.

Comment: I've tried to do that, but it's not my code that causes the problem but the `download_chromium` function in requests-html package. Tried to change it, but there is no obvious place to add `verify=false`. The code is really complex, there is no `requests.get` or anything like that.