# Getting following error while performing npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, ssl-certificate, yarnpkg

I tried reinstalling yarn, npm,

Tried **npm cache clean** and **yarn cache clean**.

Still facing the same problem while *npx create-react-app my-app*

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: self signed certificate in certificate chain".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\suryanarayan.rath\\DMS-cloud\\resilient-app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd C:\Users\suryanarayan.rath\DMS-cloud\resilient-app has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

In yarn-error.log it shows following

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1502:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:937:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:711:12)
```

I saw many similar questions which were posted earlier but could not find the right solution.

Comment: Did you try running `npm upgrade` first?

Comment: @SinanYaman Yes I have done that too, npm is up to date
``` up to date, audited 1 package in 4s ```

Comment: Have you tried to update the system certificates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293391/how-to-update-ssl-certificates-on-windows

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about Windows. Maybe give Linux a try? (Sorry, just joking).

Comment: @emi No, I want a particular solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

or

```
npm config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

Setting the strict-ssl to false resolved my issue.

Comment: This does not solves the issue, but makes it worse by using an insecure procedure (any man-in-the-middle will be able to install malware in your project) and habituates the users to do so (instead of solving the real problem in their "Operating System").