# python3 SSL certificate problem when requests_html install chromium using pyppeteer

Tags: python, macos, python-requests-html

I'm running `html.render()` from `requests_html` library. It is trying to install chromium but I am getting an error

I already tried `pip install --upgrade certifi` with and without `sudo` 
and got: `Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2019.6.16)`

I tried also running `/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates command` and got:

```
 -- pip install --upgrade certifi
Requirement already up-to-date: certifi in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (2019.6.16)
 -- removing any existing file or link
 -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle
 -- setting permissions
 -- update complete
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This is the error I got:

```
[W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start chromium download.
Download may take a few minutes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 472, in wrap_socket
    cnx.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1915, in do_handshake
    self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1647, in _raise_ssl_error
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 478, in wrap_socket
    raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
ssl.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stocks.py", line 11, in <module>
    r.html.render()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 730, in browser
    self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 473, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 714, in browser
    self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 311, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 125, in __init__
    download_chromium()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/chromium_downloader.py", line 136, in download_chromium
    extract_zip(download_zip(get_url()), DOWNLOADS_FOLDER / REVISION)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/chromium_downloader.py", line 78, in download_zip
    data = http.request('GET', url, preload_content=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 68, in request
    **urlopen_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 89, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 326, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    **response_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 399, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /chromium-browser-snapshots/Mac/575458/chrome-mac.zip (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify/42098127#42098127) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334357/2501279) have possible solutions.

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer here, and I quote:

This is a problem of urllib3 (1.25).
Workaround is to use older version of it:

pip install -U "urllib3<1.25"

from: 
https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/219

Answer (score 7):

Reference: https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/219
Configuration (spyder 4.0.1, python 3.7.3, win10)

- Install pyppdf

  > pip install pyppdf
- Then in the python script

```py
import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
```

- Output:

  > [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] start patched secure https chromium download.
  >   Download may take a few minutes.
  >   100%|| 133194757/133194757 [01:12<00:00, 1838096.92it/s]
  >   [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] 
  >   chromium download done.
  >   [W:pyppeteer.chromium_downloader] chromium extracted to: C:\Users\alexi\AppData\Local\pyppeteer\pyppeteer\local-chromium\575458

Unfortunately the (Human-understandable) details of the bug origin are not given

Answer (score 2):

The best possible answer is given in this link

https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer/issues/258

The issue seems to be with urlib3 trying to download and install chrome browser.
This requires certificate verification, which throws error otherwise.
For Anaconda setup below steps are recommended to fix this issue.

conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2.

This worked for me, and hope will work for others until pypdf library introduces new issue. Until then enjoy this fix.

Comment: @Joffrey Schmitz, I appreciate the review but feel it was a bit hasty. I tried the solution given by Jasem which didnt work. Possible reason being the problem persisting in latest versions of the packages. Also, I mentioned the environment as Anaconda, the earlier solutions were for Python framework. Since this problem was not tagged to Anaconda, I added this solution for the sake of Anaconda users.