# Plaid Quickstart - Unable to fetch link_token (Python)

Tags: python, flask, plaid

After having followed the instructions on https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview/sandbox.
I get the
[following message on the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcfbB.png) and the following  [error on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI3mp.png)  from the backend when trying to get the Plaid Sandbox up and running. How do I get rid of the Unable to fetch link_token message on the frontend? I can only assume it has to do with end point `@app.route('/api/auth', methods=['GET'])` on the backend.

```
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2021 10:58:55] "POST /api/info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2021 10:58:55] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[2021-07-28 10:58:56,017] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/create_link_token [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/cruzgonzalez/quickstart/python/server.py", line 196, in create_link_token
    response = client.link_token_create(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 769, in __call__
    return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api/plaid_api.py", line 5843, in __link_token_create
    return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 831, in call_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 406, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 193, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/api_client.py", line 452, in request
    return self.rest_client.POST(url,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/rest.py", line 264, in POST
    return self.request("POST", url,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/plaid/rest.py", line 150, in request
    r = self.pool_manager.request(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 783, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='sandbox.plaid.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /link/token/create (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Jul/2021 10:58:56] "POST /api/create_link_token HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This is my .env file

```
PLAID_CLIENT_ID='XXXXXXXXXXX'
PLAID_SECRET='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
PLAID_ENV='sandbox'
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA
# Only required for OAuth:
# Set PLAID_REDIRECT_URI to 'http://localhost:3000'
# The OAuth redirect flow requires an endpoint on the developer's website
# that the bank website should redirect to. You will need to configure
# this redirect URI for your client ID through the Plaid developer dashboard
# at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api.
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:3000'
```

And my python file: server.py

```
# Read env vars from .env file
from plaid.model.payment_amount import PaymentAmount
from plaid.model.products import Products
from plaid.model.country_code import CountryCode
from plaid.model.nullable_recipient_bacs import NullableRecipientBACS
from plaid.model.payment_initiation_address import PaymentInitiationAddress
from plaid.model.payment_initiation_recipient_create_request import PaymentInitiationRecipientCreateRequest
from plaid.model.payment_initiation_payment_create_request import PaymentInitiationPaymentCreateRequest
from plaid.model.payment_initiation_payment_get_request import PaymentInitiationPaymentGetRequest
from plaid.model.link_token_create_request_payment_initiation import LinkTokenCreateRequestPaymentInitiation
from plaid.model.item_public_token_exchange_request import ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest
from plaid.model.link_token_create_request import LinkTokenCreateRequest
from plaid.model.link_token_create_request_user import LinkTokenCreateRequestUser
from plaid.model.asset_report_create_request import AssetReportCreateRequest
from plaid.model.asset_report_create_request_options import AssetReportCreateRequestOptions
from plaid.model.asset_report_user import AssetReportUser
from plaid.model.asset_report_get_request import AssetReportGetRequest
from plaid.model.asset_report_pdf_get_request import AssetReportPDFGetRequest
from plaid.model.auth_get_request import AuthGetRequest
from plaid.model.transactions_get_request import TransactionsGetRequest
from plaid.model.transactions_get_request_options import TransactionsGetRequestOptions
from plaid.model.identity_get_request import IdentityGetRequest
from plaid.model.investments_transactions_get_request_options import InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequestOptions
from plaid.model.investments_transactions_get_request import InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequest
from plaid.model.accounts_balance_get_request import AccountsBalanceGetRequest
from plaid.model.accounts_get_request import AccountsGetRequest
from plaid.model.investments_holdings_get_request import InvestmentsHoldingsGetRequest
from plaid.model.item_get_request import ItemGetRequest
from plaid.model.institutions_get_by_id_request import InstitutionsGetByIdRequest
from plaid.api import plaid_api
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import jsonify
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import plaid
import base64
import os
import datetime
import json
import time
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()


app = Flask(__name__)

# Fill in your Plaid API keys - https://dashboard.plaid.com/account/keys
PLAID_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('PLAID_CLIENT_ID')
PLAID_SECRET = os.getenv('PLAID_SECRET')
# Use 'sandbox' to test with Plaid's Sandbox environment (username: user_good,
# password: pass_good)
# Use `development` to test with live users and credentials and `production`
# to go live
PLAID_ENV = os.getenv('PLAID_ENV', 'sandbox')
# PLAID_PRODUCTS is a comma-separated list of products to use when initializing
# Link. Note that this list must contain 'assets' in order for the app to be
# able to create and retrieve asset reports.
PLAID_PRODUCTS = os.getenv('PLAID_PRODUCTS', 'transactions').split(',')

# PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES is a comma-separated list of countries for which users
# will be able to select institutions from.
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES = os.getenv('PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES', 'US').split(',')


def empty_to_none(field):
    value = os.getenv(field)
    if value is None or len(value) == 0:
        return None
    return value

host = plaid.Environment.Sandbox

if PLAID_ENV == 'sandbox':
    host = plaid.Environment.Sandbox

if PLAID_ENV == 'development':
    host = plaid.Environment.Development

if PLAID_ENV == 'production':
    host = plaid.Environment.Production

# Parameters used for the OAuth redirect Link flow.
#
# Set PLAID_REDIRECT_URI to 'http://localhost:3000/'
# The OAuth redirect flow requires an endpoint on the developer's website
# that the bank website should redirect to. You will need to configure
# this redirect URI for your client ID through the Plaid developer dashboard
# at https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api.
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI = empty_to_none('PLAID_REDIRECT_URI')

configuration = plaid.Configuration(
    host=host,
    api_key={
        'clientId': PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
        'secret': PLAID_SECRET,
        'plaidVersion': '2020-09-14'
    }
)

api_client = plaid.ApiClient(configuration)
client = plaid_api.PlaidApi(api_client)

products = []
for product in PLAID_PRODUCTS:
    products.append(Products(product))


# We store the access_token in memory - in production, store it in a secure
# persistent data store.
access_token = None
# The payment_id is only relevant for the UK Payment Initiation product.
# We store the payment_id in memory - in production, store it in a secure
# persistent data store.
payment_id = None

item_id = None


@app.route('/api/info', methods=['POST'])
def info():
    global access_token
    global item_id
    return jsonify({
        'item_id': item_id,
        'access_token': access_token,
        'products': PLAID_PRODUCTS
    })


@app.route('/api/create_link_token_for_payment', methods=['POST'])
def create_link_token_for_payment():
    global payment_id
    try:
        request = PaymentInitiationRecipientCreateRequest(
            name='John Doe',
            bacs=NullableRecipientBACS(account='26207729', sort_code='560029'),
            address=PaymentInitiationAddress(
                street=['street name 999'],
                city='city',
                postal_code='99999',
                country='GB'
            )
        )
        response = client.payment_initiation_recipient_create(
            request)
        recipient_id = response['recipient_id']

        request = PaymentInitiationPaymentCreateRequest(
            recipient_id=recipient_id,
            reference='TestPayment',
            amount=PaymentAmount(
                currency='GBP',
                value=100.00
            )
        )
        response = client.payment_initiation_payment_create(
            request
        )
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        payment_id = response['payment_id']
        request = LinkTokenCreateRequest(
            products=[Products('payment_initiation')],
            client_name='Plaid Test',
            country_codes=list(map(lambda x: CountryCode(x), PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES)),
            language='en',
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                client_user_id=str(time.time())
            ),
            payment_initiation=LinkTokenCreateRequestPaymentInitiation(
                payment_id=payment_id
            )
        )
        response = client.link_token_create(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        return json.loads(e.body)


@app.route('/api/create_link_token', methods=['POST'])
def create_link_token():
    try:
        request = LinkTokenCreateRequest(
            products=products,
            client_name="Plaid Quickstart",
            country_codes=list(map(lambda x: CountryCode(x), PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES)),
            language='en',
            user=LinkTokenCreateRequestUser(
                client_user_id=str(time.time())
            )
        )

        # create link token
        response = client.link_token_create(request)
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        return json.loads(e.body)


# Exchange token flow - exchange a Link public_token for
# an API access_token
# https://plaid.com/docs/#exchange-token-flow


@app.route('/api/set_access_token', methods=['POST'])
def get_access_token():
    global access_token
    global item_id
    public_token = request.form['public_token']
    try:
        exchange_request = ItemPublicTokenExchangeRequest(
            public_token=public_token)
        exchange_response = client.item_public_token_exchange(exchange_request)
        access_token = exchange_response['access_token']
        item_id = exchange_response['item_id']
        return jsonify(exchange_response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        return json.loads(e.body)


# Retrieve ACH or ETF account numbers for an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#auth


@app.route('/api/auth', methods=['GET'])
def get_auth():
    try:
       request = AuthGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token
        )
       response = client.auth_get(request)
       pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
       return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve Transactions for an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#transactions


@app.route('/api/transactions', methods=['GET'])
def get_transactions():
    # Pull transactions for the last 30 days
    start_date = (datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30))
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        options = TransactionsGetRequestOptions()
        request = TransactionsGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token,
            start_date=start_date.date(),
            end_date=end_date.date(),
            options=options
        )
        response = client.transactions_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve Identity data for an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#identity


@app.route('/api/identity', methods=['GET'])
def get_identity():
    try:
        request = IdentityGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token
        )
        response = client.identity_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(
            {'error': None, 'identity': response.to_dict()['accounts']})
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve real-time balance data for each of an Item's accounts
# https://plaid.com/docs/#balance


@app.route('/api/balance', methods=['GET'])
def get_balance():
    try:
        request = AccountsBalanceGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token
        )
        response = client.accounts_balance_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve an Item's accounts
# https://plaid.com/docs/#accounts


@app.route('/api/accounts', methods=['GET'])
def get_accounts():
    try:
        request = AccountsGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token
        )
        response = client.accounts_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(response.to_dict())
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Create and then retrieve an Asset Report for one or more Items. Note that an
# Asset Report can contain up to 100 items, but for simplicity we're only
# including one Item here.
# https://plaid.com/docs/#assets


@app.route('/api/assets', methods=['GET'])
def get_assets():
    try:
        request = AssetReportCreateRequest(
            access_tokens=[access_token],
            days_requested=60,
            options=AssetReportCreateRequestOptions(
                webhook='https://www.example.com',
                client_report_id='123',
                user=AssetReportUser(
                    client_user_id='789',
                    first_name='Jane',
                    middle_name='Leah',
                    last_name='Doe',
                    ssn='123-45-6789',
                    phone_number='(555) 123-4567',
                    email='jane.doe@example.com',
                )
            )
        )

        response = client.asset_report_create(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        asset_report_token = response['asset_report_token']
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)

    # Poll for the completion of the Asset Report.
    num_retries_remaining = 20
    asset_report_json = None
    while num_retries_remaining > 0:
        try:
            request = AssetReportGetRequest(
                asset_report_token=asset_report_token,
            )
            response = client.asset_report_get(request)
            asset_report_json = response['report']
            break
        except plaid.ApiException as e:
            response = json.loads(e.body)
            if response['error_code'] == 'PRODUCT_NOT_READY':
                num_retries_remaining -= 1
                time.sleep(1)
                continue
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)
    if asset_report_json is None:
        return jsonify({'error': {'status_code': e.status, 'display_message':
                                  'Timed out when polling for Asset Report', 'error_code': '', 'error_type': ''}})

    asset_report_pdf = None
    try:
        request = AssetReportPDFGetRequest(
            asset_report_token=asset_report_token,
        )
        pdf = client.asset_report_pdf_get(request)
        return jsonify({
            'error': None,
            'json': asset_report_json.to_dict(),
            'pdf': base64.b64encode(pdf.read()).decode('utf-8'),
        })
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve investment holdings data for an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#investments


@app.route('/api/holdings', methods=['GET'])
def get_holdings():
    try:
        request = InvestmentsHoldingsGetRequest(access_token=access_token)
        response = client.investments_holdings_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify({'error': None, 'holdings': response.to_dict()})
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve Investment Transactions for an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#investments


@app.route('/api/investment_transactions', methods=['GET'])
def get_investment_transactions():
    # Pull transactions for the last 30 days

    start_date = (datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=(30)))
    end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    try:
        options = InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequestOptions()
        request = InvestmentsTransactionsGetRequest(
            access_token=access_token,
            start_date=start_date.date(),
            end_date=end_date.date(),
            options=options
        )
        response = client.investment_transactions_get(
            request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify(
            {'error': None, 'investment_transactions': response.to_dict()})

    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# This functionality is only relevant for the UK Payment Initiation product.
# Retrieve Payment for a specified Payment ID


@app.route('/api/payment', methods=['GET'])
def payment():
    global payment_id
    try:
        request = PaymentInitiationPaymentGetRequest(payment_id=payment_id)
        response = client.payment_initiation_payment_get(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        return jsonify({'error': None, 'payment': response.to_dict()})
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)


# Retrieve high-level information about an Item
# https://plaid.com/docs/#retrieve-item


@app.route('/api/item', methods=['GET'])
def item():
    try:
        request = ItemGetRequest(access_token=access_token)
        response = client.item_get(request)
        request = InstitutionsGetByIdRequest(
            institution_id=response['item']['institution_id'],
            country_codes=list(map(lambda x: CountryCode(x), PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES))
        )
        institution_response = client.institutions_get_by_id(request)
        pretty_print_response(response.to_dict())
        pretty_print_response(institution_response.to_dict())
        return jsonify({'error': None, 'item': response.to_dict()[
            'item'], 'institution': institution_response.to_dict()['institution']})
    except plaid.ApiException as e:
        error_response = format_error(e)
        return jsonify(error_response)

def pretty_print_response(response):
  print(json.dumps(response, indent=2, sort_keys=True, default=str))

def format_error(e):
    response = json.loads(e.body)
    return {'error': {'status_code': e.status, 'display_message':
                      response['error_message'], 'error_code': response['error_code'], 'error_type': response['error_type']}}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=os.getenv('PORT', 8000))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, we have figured out why python 3.9 does not work with the Quickstart.  Your SSLCertVerificationError is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098126/mac-osx-python-ssl-sslerror-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify)

run this in your terminal to install root certificates:

`open /Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command`

Answer (score 1):

This can also be caused by an outdated `requests` package. My team had the same issue and upgrading `requests` to the latest version (currently 2.27.1) solved it.