# How to fix "Unable to fetch link_token" with Plaid API?

Tags: python, plaid

I followed the instructions here: https://dashboard.plaid.com/overview/sandbox.

I have everything setup the way it should, my .env looks like this:

```
    PLAID_CLIENT_ID=myclientid
    PLAID_SECRET=mysandboxsecret
    PLAID_ENV=sandbox
    PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions
    PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=US,CA
    PLAID_REDIRECT_URI='http://localhost:3000/'
```

I did try leaving URI blank as well - made no difference.

For some reason, I continue to get this error when I visit http://localhost:3000 after running `npm start`

> Unable to fetch link_token: please make sure your backend server is running and that your .env file has been configured correctly.

The error code, error type, and error message are all blank.

Here are the terminal outputs for `./start.sh` & `npm start`

###### `./start.sh`

```
     * Serving Flask app "server" (lazy loading)
     * Environment: production
       WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
       Use a production WSGI server instead.
     * Debug mode: off
     * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2022 20:05:45] "POST /api/info HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2022 20:05:45] "POST /api/create_link_token HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

###### `npm start`

```
> plaid_react_quickstart@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

[HPM] Proxy created: /  ->  http://localhost:8000
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.1.45/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/user/plaid/quickstart/frontend/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
Compiled with warnings.

src/dataUtilities.ts
  Line 11:3:  'AssetReportGetResponse' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Does anyone familiar with Plaid API know how to fix this?

It feels like the API/quickstart process has changed a bit since those postings.

EDIT:

I re-cloned the repo and started from step 1 and re-did everything. It all works now. I traced the issue back to an extra digit at the end of my SECRET. Thank you Alex for the help, but it was all a silly mistake. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can always get more data about what went wrong by looking at the activity log at https://dashboard.plaid.com/activity/logs. That said, the most common causes of this issue are the following:

- Specifying a REDIRECT_URI in the .env file but not adding it to "allowed redirect uris" at  https://dashboard.plaid.com/team/api
- Being on Windows and not cloning the repo in a manner that preserves symlinks, which you can do like this:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true https://github.com/plaid/quickstart
```

Comment: So I just checked the activity log and don't see a single entry in there.

Also, I did run with and without REDIRECT_URI specified in the .env file (just to be clear I did add the URI to the dashboard).

 I am on Mac OS trying to do this through python. Does my python version matter? I am running 3.10.2 VENV. I installed everything in the requirements.txt.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console in your browser? It appears the frontend successfully called your server to get a link_token and got a 200 response back, but maybe something else went wrong on the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

try this answer as well, seems like python3.9 certificates are missing for mac os
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68595419/6013354