# Anaconda Prompt is having an issue with SSL certificates

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I wanted to create a virtual environment in conda prompt:

```
conda create --name name_of_venv
```

I am getting error:

> Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done Solving
> environment: done
>
> CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate
> verification issue.
>
> Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443):
> Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json
> (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

The same error I get with anaconda navigator too.

Comment: Are you running on macos? You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42098127/6383431

Comment: No, I am using windows 10

Comment: you can look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862850/conda-ssl-errror/77862937#77862937

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not the best thing to do in terms of security, you can set SSL verify = FALSE as follow:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Comment: Actually I have found this method, but as you mentioned it is not the best thing to do. All the resources that I have been through and they have also suggested the same. Is there any other way around?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this too, I solved by close my VPN

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34555208)